# User defined function with a variable workbook argument

Tags: excel, vba, function, user-defined-functions

I want to build a function that checks if a value is in a workbook and then give me back true or false so I can use the result in a sub that loops the result.

**I wrote this:**

```vb
Function check(A As String, rg As Range) As Boolean
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In rg
    If cell.Value = a Then
        check = True
        Exit Function
    Else
        check= False
    End If
Next cell
End Function
```

This gives back nothing.

If I add in the function the workbooks range, for instance:

```
workbook(x).worksheet(y).range("a1:a100")
```

This works, but I would like to use this function with different workbook range. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you use the UDF:

```
Sub Morresi()
    MsgBox check("A", Range("A1:A100"))
End Sub
```

will pass the range on the active sheet of the active workbook, but:

```
Sub Morresi2()
    MsgBox check("A", Workbooks("xxx.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1:A100"))
End Sub
```

will pass the range on a specific open workbook and a specific sheet on that workbook.

Comment: thank you, i think i found what i did wrong.